# Elements of ConcurrentQueue(Of T) cannot be widened

Tags: .net, vb.net, generics, casting, type-parameter

Let's say I have this Sub:

```
Sub Process(InputQueue as ConcurrentQueue(Of Object))
    .... some codes ....
End Sub
```

Now I have this

```
Class JobDesc
    .... some codes ....
End Class

Dim MainJobQueue As New ConcurrentQueue(Of JobDesc)
```

Why does VB.Net complain if I try to pass `MainJobQueue` as a parameter to `Process()`?

That is, doing this:

```
Process(MainJobQueue)
```

Will result in the following error message:

> Value of type 'ConcurrentQueue(Of JobDesc)' cannot be converted to 'ConcurrentQueue(Of Object)'.

Is not `JobDesc` a subclass of `Object`, hence casting `JobDesc` to `Object` will be a 'widening' instead of narrowing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is not JobDesc a subclass of Object, hence casting JobDesc to Object will be a 'widening' instead of narrowing?

Yes, but the problem is that `ConcurrentQueue` is a *mutable* collection.

So its type parameter does not only define what objects you can get out of it, but also what *new* elements it will accept.

If you could straight-up cast it to `ConcurrentQueue(of Object)`, you could then do this:

```
Sub Process(InputQueue as ConcurrentQueue(Of Object))
    InputQueue.Enqueue("Whoops, this is not a JobDesc!")
End Sub

Process(MainQueue)

Dim getLatestJob = MainQueue.Dequeue() // WTF, why did it give me a String?
```

(Well, in theory. If you actually managed to compile this, the program would crash with `InvalidCastException`.)

Now, if you *don't* plan to add any non-`JobDesc` elements to the queue, you have a couple of options.

- You can enforce the type constraint by writing `Process` as a generic method instead.

  ```
  Sub Process(Of SomeType)(InputQueue as ConcurrentQueue(Of SomeType))
       InputQueue.Enqueue("Whoops, this is not a SomeType!")
       // will not compile, input is not SomeType
  End Sub
  ```
- Or, you can cast `ConcurrentQueue` to a base class or interface like `IEnumerable(Of T)`, which does *not* allow adding new elements to the collection, and therefore can be safely cast to a a broader type like `Object` (technical term: `covariant`).

  ```
   Dim MainQueueReadOnly As IEnumerable(Of JobDesc) = MainQueue

   Sub Process(InputQueue as IEnumerable(Of Object))
       InputQueue.Enqueue(anything) 
       // will not compile as IEnumerable doesn't have an .Enqueue method
   End Sub
  ```

If you *do*, however, intend to stick some `Object`s in the queue, then your only option is to create a *new, different* collection from `InputQueue`, one that will accept elements of types other than `JobDesc`.

```
Dim newQueue As New ConcurrentQueue(Of Object)(MainJobQueue)
```

Comment: Explanation with meat and many great solutions, that I believe will be useful for anyone facing a similar, but not quite the same, situation. You have my upvote and my checkmark :-)

Answer (score 2):

You could create a generic method something like this (that is if i still correctly remember vb.net)

```
Sub Process(of T as Object)(InputQueue as ConcurrentQueue(Of T))
```

Comment: Just `Process(Of T)` :)

Comment: I specifically added `as Object`, to look more like the question that was asked :)

Comment: Ah, gotcha! Makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't working as you expect because `ConcurrentQueue` is not covariant. From the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx):

> **Covariance** enables you to use a more derived type than originally specified.
>
> You can assign an instance of IEnumerable (IEnumerable(Of Derived) in Visual Basic) to a variable of type `IEnumerable<Base>`.

If you change your method to accept an `IEnumerable(Of Object)` or `IReadOnlyList(Of Object)`, it'll compile just fine, because those interfaces **are** covariant:

```
Sub Process(InputQueue As IEnumerable(Of Object))
    '....some codes ....
End Sub
```